# Background worker does not work properly in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, desktop

i want to show Temporary files in a datagrid , hence it is a long term  process i use  background worker in my C# .net WPF application .

my Code is

```
 private System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker _background = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();

   private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          _background.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

    public MainWindow()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           this._background.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(_background_DoWork);
           this._background.RunWorkerCompleted += new       
           RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(_background_RunWorkerCompleted);
           this._background.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
           _background.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

       }


void _background_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)

{

this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            FileInfo[] files = new   
            DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()).GetFiles();

            foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
            {
                if (fi != null)              
                 {                 
                    dataGrid1.Items.Add(fi);           

                }
            }           
        }
        catch { }
    }));
}

void _background_RunWorkerCompleted(object sen, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
      {

          if (e.Cancelled)
          {
             MessageBox.Show("Cancelled");
          }
          else if (e.Error != null)
          {
               MessageBox.Show("Exception Thrown");
          }

     }
```

All the code is running but it hangs when datagrid is loading means my UI does not response when program is running .

What modification is needed to run background worker smoothly in the above condition ?

Beside it , if i want to add a ProgressBar which progressed along with this application then what i have to do ?

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

By using `this.Dispatcher.Invoke`, you are effectively marshalling the work back to the UI thread. This makes no sense: you are blocking the UI thread while this action is being performed.

Split the work in two parts:

- the slow part, which is retrieving the files and should be done outside the `Dispatcher.Invoke`
- the UI update, which must be done in `Dispatcher.Invoke`, or (better) in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.

The background worker component is made exactly so that you don't need to dispatch UI work manually using the dispatcher. For example, you could store the files in a field which you fill in the `DoWork` method, and use to fill the datagrid in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event:

```
FileInfo[] files;

void _background_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    files = new DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()).GetFiles();
}

void _background_RunWorkerCompleted(object sen, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cancelled");
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exception Thrown");
    }
    else 
    { 
         foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
         {
              dataGrid1.Items.Add(fi);           
         }
    }
}
```

Note: if you are using C# 5, you now have an even easier way, using the `async/await` feature. All you need is something like this:

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        try
        {
            var files = await Task.Run(() => 
                new DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()).GetFiles()
            );
            foreach (var f in files)
                this.dataGrid1.Items.Add(f.Name);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception thrown!"); // do proper error handling here...
        }
        finally
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

All the rest of the cruft is taken care of by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383574.aspx).

This line:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke
```

executes code synchronously at main thread, so there are no benefits from using of `BackgroudWorker` such a way, because `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` returns only when all files in directory are enumerated.

On the other hand, `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` is lazy. You can write something like this:

```
void _background_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var info = new DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath());

    // now enumeration happens in background
    foreach (var fi in info.EnumerateFiles())
    {
        // main thread in used only when there is next enumeration result available
        Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => dataGrid1.Items.Add(fi)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to take this action  off the Dispatcher:

```
FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()).GetFiles();
```

It should only do small and quick operations that involve UI access or modification. See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx

Your heavy work can be done by the BackgroundWorker and use the Dispatcher to update the dataGrid.Items collection.

Try to use the Dispatcher using:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be updating the UI in either the RunWorkerComplete or ProgressChanged event handlers.

Try something like this:

```
    public Program()
    {
        w = new BackgroundWorker();
        w.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(w_DoWork);
        w.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(w_ProgressChanged);
        w.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(w_RunWorkerCompleted);
        w.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        w.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        w.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void w_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileInfo[] files = e.Result as FileInfo[];
        foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
        {
            //dataGrid1.Items.Add(fi);  
        }
    }

    void w_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileInfo fi = e.UserState as FileInfo;
        //dataGrid1.Items.Add(fi);  
    }

    void w_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var w = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo(
            Path.GetTempPath()).GetFiles();

        // Using ProgressChanged
        foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
        {
            w.ReportProgress(0, fi);
        }

        // Using RunWorkerCompleted
        e.Result = files;
    }
```

Also, there is no need for the try/catch in dowork, exceptions are automatically caught and reported as errors in the runworkercomplete event.